# Why does this pointer still work in Visual Studio 2012 professional?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int *f1(int x) {
    return &x;
}

void f2(int a, int b, int c){

    cout<<a<<endl;
}

int main() {

    cout<<"hari Hari"<<endl;

    int *x;
    x = f1(90);
    f2(3,45,2);

    cout<<*x<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

now as f1 return pointer to stack, which was suppose to overwritten by f2, and expected output should be looks something like this 
"
hari Hari
3
3
"
but actually I get right answer, and my actual output is,
"
hari Hari
3
90
"
I can't understand why it is not overwrite the value of f1 function's 'x'.

Comment: I'm certain this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're relying on undefined behavior, which means you can't rely on it behaving in any particular way.  In your case, you just got "lucky".

Comment: But as I know stack allocations are contiguous, that is laid out end-to-end, and heap allocations are not necessarily contiguous so can you please give some idea of memory model which it manage here.

Comment: You could print out the addresses & see for yourself.